# Weird crippled letters in GTK windows

Tags: fonts, gtk, bugs

I have recently discovered this bug which often occurs after I run a memory-sensitive application (such as Chromium). It somehow affects GTK - some letters in all GTK-based UIs become weirdly messed up (see the screenshot).

[image: Weirdly messed up font - this is how my browser tabs look after the bug occurs]

The only fix I have found so far is to reboot the system. I suppose that it somehow clears the font cache. Still, I would feel much happier if somebody helped me find the origin of the bug.

I use:

- Debian Jessie (stable)
- Awesome Window Manager (stable)

Cheers! Pete.

EDIT: My hardware is **Dell Latitude E4200**. [Click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/of91ygfl2bx1x0x/info.tar.gz?dl=0) to download package with information about my software configuration.

Comment: I got crippled letters and sometimes broken graphics elements (e.g. icons, rounded window border corners and other small stuff) too with **Debian8/Jessie** running **Gnome3** on all my **Thinkpad T60** notebooks (all using **ATI Radeon X1300** graphics).

Comment: Can you add to question, info about graphics hardware, and drivers, and anything else you think may be relevant.

Comment: My hardware is **Dell Latitude E4200**. I also use Gnome3 btw. I have packed all information about my software into [this neat package](https://www.dropbox.com/s/of91ygfl2bx1x0x/info.tar.gz?dl=0). Check the readme for details.

Comment: `xterm -fn -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--20-200-75-75-c-100-iso10646-1` (and with other members of that font family) does not show degrading fonts even if the desktop fonts are degraded. `xterm -fa monospace` shows the described effect and sometimes letters vanish completely depending on the background/foreground combination. Maybe such information helps a bit to get nearer to the points causing this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will try next time I see the bug. Meanwhile, I've found a temporary fix without rebooting in [http://askubuntu.com/questions/606447/broken-fonts-in-kde-kubuntu-14-10](this article). When I see the bug in some window, I run `sudo fc-cache -srv; fc-cache -rv` and then close and reopen the window - the crippled letters do not appear again. So my suspicions are correct, it's the font cache.